# Access source table view in performDropWith delegate callback

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added the drag and drop functionality using iOS 11 `UITableViewDragDelegate`/`UITableViewDropDelegate` pair for multiple table views.

Is there any way for me to get access to the source table object so that I can call `.reloadData()` on it?

Comment: what you mean "Is there any way for me to get access to the source table object"

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me the part

> Is there any way for me to get access to the source table object

however you can use property observer `didSet` to reload the tableView each time the variable modified.

something like this should work,

```
var dataSrouce: [String] = [] { // your data source object. 
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData() // reload the tableView using that data source. 
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I have 20 table views and the user drags from one to whichever he wants. The delegate method is called in the target on the import. How do i get access to the source table view?

Comment: you want to reload the tableview because the datasource changed right ?

Comment: implement that on each data source you are using and it will automatically reload any tableView that have any changes in the dataSource.

Comment: No, i want to reload it only if we finished a successful drop. At the moment I have to reload on dragEnd

Comment: Mate did you read the question? Datasource does NOT change. User drags ONE item across tables.

Comment: Datasource does not change, thats changes a lot, thanks for feedback